# How to fix error java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: android, arraylist, autocompletetextview

I have some problem with `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. When I deleted one characater or more in my autocompletetext I got force close. Anybody knows what happen with that ? and what is the solution for that problem ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding and deleting something from your collection at same point of time. By doing this, you are structurally modifying the collections more than once at single point of time. Hence you are getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`, which is the result of "Fail-Fast" iterators being used in your collections.
You can have a look at this link which explains fail-safe and fail-fast iterators.
[what-is-fail-safe-fail-fast-iterators-in-java-how-they-are-implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377407/what-is-fail-safe-fail-fast-iterators-in-java-how-they-are-implemented) and checkout the answer written by Stephen C.

Comment: Do you have some example of code to solve that problem ?

Comment: It's pretty simple, like I said, if you are trying to modify your collection structurally at a same given point of time, the iterator which you are using to iterate through that collection will fail. Check this example snippet below:
`ArrayList<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
sampleList.add("hello");
sampleList.add("world");
Iterator<String> sampleListItr = sampleList.iterator();
//If you try to remove first item from list, your iterator fails
sampleList.remove(0);
while(sampleListItr.hasNext()){
System.out.println(sampleListItr.next());
}`
So try to avoid iterators.

Comment: You can avoid that problem by not using iterators. Java 8 provides you `foreach` method to help you iterate over any collections.