# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when removing elements from arraylist even with iterators

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to delete content from two arrayLists when a particular condition is satisfied. But when the condition satisfied I get Concurrent modification error. After searching on internet I saw the solution to fix this using the iterator concept but that also doesn't work.

Here is the two code variations that I tried: [my code is in Kotlin]

1st variation: instantly get error after removing

```
        var index = 0
        for (snap: DataSnapshot in snaps){
            if (snap.key == snapshot.key){
                snaps.removeAt(index)
                emailOfSenders.removeAt(index)
            }

            index++
        }
```

2nd variation: works if the items are less than 3 in the arraylist, but if items are 3 or more than 3 I get the same error

```
        var index = 0

        val iter: Iterator<DataSnapshot> = snaps.iterator()
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            val snap: DataSnapshot = iter.next()
            if (snap.key == snapshot.key){
                snaps.removeAt(index)
                emailOfSenders.removeAt(index)
            }

            index++
        }
```

Error log:

```
2020-11-18 13:52:32.829 18935-18935/com.rofy.snapyandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rofy.snapyandroid, PID: 18935
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
        at com.rofy.snapyandroid.SnapsActivity$onCreate$1.onChildRemoved(SnapsActivity.kt:54)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(ChildEventRegistration.java:88)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

More info: I am creating a snapchat clone app and I'm using google's firebase for it everything works perfectly i.e uploading,doenloading,deleting in the firebase. so i don't think this is a firebase issue

Comment: The scenario where it's , should be the case where matched element is last in list. And with iterator you can use only iterator.remove() method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are iterating over a `collection` using an `iterator` then you can only modify the `collection` using iterator's mutator methods, if you try to modify the collection using collection's mutator methods (remove,set etc) then `iterator` throws `ConcurrentModificationException`, this is known as [fail-fast property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377407/what-are-fail-safe-fail-fast-iterators-in-java) of iterators.

in your case instead of doing `snaps.removeAt(index)`, you should do `iterator.remove()`

Please note that `iterator.remove` removes the last element returned by the iterator. So in order to remove an element you have to call `next()` method first. For example lets say you wanted to remove first element. to achieve this you will have to do the following.

```
iterator.next()
iterator.remove() // Removes the element returned by next
```

> works if the items are less than 3 in the arraylist, but if items are
> 3 or more than 3 I get the same error

This is because, the `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown by `next()` method, and because in case of 1 or 2 elements it only gets called once, that to before any modification, so you don't get any error. In above cases following steps are executed:

```
1. iterator.hasNext()      // returns true 
2. iterator.next()         // works fine, since we have not modified collection yet
3. snaps.removeAt(index)   // removes one element
4. iterator.hasNext()      // returns false as there is only one element in list
5. iterator.next           // this line is not executed and hence no error
```

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation :) . I finally understood what I was doing wrong. Your solution helped me. THANK YOU :D